# Regex to validate that the first letter of a word in input field is not a special character

Tags: angularjs, regex, pattern-matching, ng-pattern

I am using angularjs. I want to use validation for my name field. I am a beginner in regex expressions. I want that the first letter of the name is not a special Character. For E.g My$Repo should be valid and $MyRepo is invalid.

I am using ng-pattern to validate the name field. What regex expression should i use? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `^\w.*$`, which means "a string of at least one character, with the initial character that is a letter from Latin alphabet, a digit, or an underscore.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/tQQOAF/1)

Comment: along with the provided validation (with the initial character that is a letter from Latin alphabet, a digit, or an underscore) i need to allow some special characters in between or end other than /?\%*:|"<.> . Appreciate your help.

Comment: i tried with the below regex ^\w[^\<.>?*:\\"\/|%\ ]*$. Please let me know whetner this is correct way or any changes to be made.

Comment: @shaaa This looks right, all you need is to make sure that all your special characters are properly escaped.

Comment: There is a problem in the above Regex. when am using this regex if i give space and write another word it is not accepting. Here is the link. https://regex101.com/r/tQQOAF/3. Any help on this?

Comment: @shaaa Regex does not accept strings with spaces, because your regex wants complete words, `^` to `$`, and prohibits spaces (the space before `]` is on the exclusion list).

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of "special" characters, but few "non-special"; I would specify what *is* allowed:

```
^[a-zA-Z].*
```

This means "any Latin letter followed by anything".

To allow letters from any alphabet:

```
^\p{L}.*
```

This means "any letter from any alphabet followed by anything".

Answer (score -1):

The ragex for special characters in the beginning is `/^[$!@#%^&*(\-)_+=-\][{}|';,./?><:"]/g`